# Turn a image to grayscale in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm a newbie to tensorflow and keras, and I'm trying to create a CNN model for The Street View House Numbers (SVHN) dataset. The dataset contains  color images, and I want to turn them in grayscale. I found some code on the web that claims they're turning image to grayscale, but it just changes colors.

People are reading the second image with a gray colormap. Is there any way to **actually** turn this image to grayscale?
(I do not know how to process an image in this kind of programming languages. If this is a dumb question, please forgive me and provide a brief explain.)
I provided images and code below, I'll be grateful for any help.

**Code:**

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Read picture:
picture = plt.imread('google.jpg')

print("google logo's shape is: ",picture.shape) #(500, 500, 3)

#saving picture as an np array:
pic_array = np.array(picture)

#Turning image to grayscale
grayscale_pic = np.expand_dims(np.dot(pic_array[...,:3],[0.299, 0.587, 0.144]),axis = 0)

#Dimensions shifted, (probly my mistake):
grayscale_pic = np.moveaxis(grayscale_pic, 0, -1)

print("shape of grayscale pic = ", grayscale_pic.shape) # (500, 500, 1)

plt.imshow(picture)         #Figure_1
plt.show()
plt.imshow(grayscale_pic)   #Figure_2
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `plt.imshow(grayscale_pic, cmap='gray')` Matplotlib uses the `viridis` colormap by default to pseudo-colorize grayscale images. Explicitly using the `gray` colormap does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

U can convert a normal image to grayscale using `opencv` like this:

```
import cv2
gray = cv2.cvtColor(picture,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

If u prefer `numpy` over `opencv`, then u can use this:

```
gray = np.dot(picture[...,:3], [0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140])
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can use `matplotlib` with weights:

---

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

an_image = plt.imread('google.png')
rgb_weights = [0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140]
grayscale_image = np.dot(an_image[..., :3], rgb_weights)
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(grayscale_image, cmap=plt.get_cmap("gray"), aspect='auto')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

---

If you remove `aspect='auto'` parameter:

[image]

---

- or you can use `opencv`

```py
import cv2

an_image = cv2.imread("google.png")
grey_image = cv2.cvtColor(an_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

[image]

---

- or you can use `PIL` library

```py
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('google.png').convert('LA')
```

`LA` mode is L (8-bit pixels, black and white) with ALPHA desinged for .gif and .png. If your images are .jpeg use `L`.

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There can be several ways to do this. One potential way is to utilize [`PIL(Pillow)`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html) library:

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

picture = Image.open('google.jpg')
grayscale_pic = picture.convert('LA')
grayscale_pic.save('grayscale.png')

fig,ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)

plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.imshow(picture)
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.imshow(grayscale_pic)
plt.show()
```

**Output**:

[image]